# Notifications in db

Tags: php, ajax, notifications

I want to perform notifications on my web site. I'll for them on client side with an ajax request every 300 seconds, then I want a response from my server. I can do all of this things, but I don't know how to save the notifications. I'm thinking to save every notifications in a table in my db, then I perform a query with PHP every time i have a request from the clients. There are other ways to do this?

Comment: First of all, how are you planning to achieve something 'real-time' if you only poll every 300 seconds. 
Also, why do you want to save the notifications, what do you need them for? What is the context of your project?

Comment: Well, there are other ways to perform the notifications, such as using web sockets.  But it sounds like you're not asking about the notifications themselves, but rather how to persist data on the server?  Generally a database is the way to go for that, yes.

Comment: "Real time notifications", "Request every 300 seconds" ... Thats surely not real time. Use something like websockets or learn the observer pattern in PHP.

Comment: Sorry, i wasn't clear. I can use also real time notifications, but i think that using a request every 300 seconds (or something like that) can be enough for my project. I don't know if there are other ways to perform this kind of notifications. Then I want to know if storing all the notifications in one table is too much for the db.

Comment: Can you be more clear on what kind of notifications you are talking about, i.e. give us an example of the payload of such a notification. Also, can you be more clear on the context of your project with the purpose of giving us a more intuitive idea of what you want/

Comment: An example of notification is: "Carl published red.txt". Carl is an user and red.txt a file. So, Carl is a row of the table Users, Red.txt is a row of table Files. I'm thinking to create a table Notifications where i put the IDs of users and files, the Ts and a text value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem. I'm using ajax request every 300 seconds and all my notifications are in my db. It works fine and it seems to be a good solution.